# Receiver not receiving intent

Tags: android

Seems likes a no-brainer. Why is my receiver receiving the intent? I'm declaring this receiver in the `onCreate` method in my main activity class.

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(WidgetProvider.ACTION_OPEN_ACTIVITY);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // No toast is shown. 
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Intent received",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, filter);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(WidgetProvider.ACTION_OPEN_ACTIVITY);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
intent.setAction(WidgetProvider.ACTION_OPEN_ACTIVITY);
```

with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WidgetProvider.ACTION_OPEN_ACTIVITY);
```

You cannot use an explicit `Intent` with a dynamically-registered receiver and `MainActivity` is not a `BroadcastReceiver`.